# Trigger a function when iframe completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to trigger a function when an `iframe` on the same page is loaded completely.

Comment: is the iframe on same domain?

Comment: @Bernhard no its not.

Comment: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/   here you can rede abaut iframe onload with cross domain iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `onload` Event

Example:

```
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() {
    // put your code here
}
```